# Should I use HTML/CSS/jQuery, or an open source framework for bar and pie charts in iPad applications?

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, graph

I need to create a horizontal bar chart and pie chart in my iPad application. I need to bind json data in the charts.

I already tried using coreplot and iosplot, but it doesn’t look nice.

I didn’t find anything apt when searching, so I started to try jQuery, CSS and HTML

This is my first time working with jQuery (I need to use KENDU UI), so I don’t have a good idea of how to create charts in jQuery.

My question is: is it better to work with jQuery or to use open source frameworks in XCode?

Answer (score 0):

Simply You can use FusionCharts in your xcode project which is in jQuery too

[Bar charts and Graph in jQuery for Xcode](http://www.fusioncharts.com/jquery/)

Hope it helps you...